# Share multiple files via UIActivityViewController to Dropbox

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

My application works with HealthKit data in order to create some reports from the user's workout data and exports them to one or more files (mainly CSV and sometimes GPX files). To allow the user to access these files I present the standard `UIActivityViewController` passing as items an array of file as `[URL]` and no application activities ([this](https://github.com/piscoTech/Workout/blob/f4123621ee7567c4e2fb7a2fb1991f071126167c/Workout/Controller/WorkoutTVC.swift#L340) is the relevant line in the code where `files` is the array of `URL`s).

It all works without issues, but today one of my users reported that when multiple files are exported and Dropbox is selected as the target for sharing the files, only the first one is saved and the others are ignored. Is there something I can do about it or is an issue that must be solved by Dropbox? To my understanding it should be the latter, but I can be missing something.

If they are relevant, here are two screenshot of the sharing screen under iOS 13: in the first only one CSV file is being shared and there's a *Save to Dropbox* option, in the second I'm sharing 2 CSV and 1 GPX files and that option is no longer there. In the second case there's still *Copy to Dropbox* (hidden) and it leads to only one file being saved, if I use *Save to Files*, all 3 files are correctly saved.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Marco,

You are right, this is a Dropbox issue, not an issue with your apps export. It looks like the Dropbox app, by default, only accepts one file when received from the export action. Here is the workaround. The native iOS Files app will accept multiple export files and it is possible to add the Dropbox folders to the Files app, effectively allowing the multiple files to be uploaded to Dropbox.

Adding Dropbox to Files app:

1. Open Files app, on the app main screen, click the three dots in the upper right corner, and select edit.
2. This will show a ghosted Dropbox file with a toggle switch next to it, tap to add Dropbox to the list of available files.

Exporting the Multiple Files to Dropbox:

3. Once steps 1 and 2 are complete, go to the desired export app, and select the file you want to export.
4. In the list of export options, select the iOS Files app (not Dropbox), and then select the Dropbox file within the Files app. Then you can select the Dropbox sub-folder you want the multiple export files to be placed in.

That accomplishes the desired goal in the same number of steps as exporting to DropBox.